# Output Sas report as a dataset

Tags: sas

Do anyone know how i get the parameter estimate and variables as dataset (columns) instead of a sas report.
[image: Screenshot of the sas report]

I tried to use output statement in my code but can't get parameter estimate and variables name in columns. Here is my code:

```
PROC REG DATA=WORK.SORTTempTableSorted
        PLOTS(ONLY)=ALL

    ;


    Linear_Regression_Model: MODEL logsnit = Global Government Healthcare "Basic Materials"n "Consumer Goods"n "Consumer Services"n Energy Financials Industrials Technology "Telecommunications Services"n Utilities Asia Europe Japan "Lat.Amer"n "Africa & Middle East"n AustralAsia "N.Amer"n A AA AAA B BB BBB CCC Senior Sub

/       SELECTION=NONE

        NOINT
        PCORR1 PCORR2
    ;
    Restrict Government+Healthcare+"Basic Materials"n+"Consumer Goods"n+"Consumer Services"n+Energy+Financials+Industrials+Technology+"Telecommunications Services"n+Utilities=0;
    Restrict Asia+Europe+Japan+"Lat.Amer"n+"Africa & Middle East"n+AustralAsia+"N.Amer"n=0;
Restrict A+AA+AAA+B+BB+BBB+CCC=0;
Restrict Senior+Sub=0
;
RUN;
Output out=work.test

/*COOKD, COVRATIO, DFFITS, H, L95, L95M, LCL, LCLM, OUT, P, PRED, 
              PREDICTED, PRESS, R, RESIDUAL, RSTUDENT, STDI, STDP, STDR, STUDENT, U95, U95M, UCL, UCLM*/; 
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im away from SAS but all output you can see can be saved as a dataset. You see the tablename SAS creates in proc reg here:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect051.htm

So add (somewhere before the run statement):

ods output ParameterEstimates=YourName;

And you should get what you want.